# Selenium IDE to load Suites and Testcases from URL?

Tags: selenium

I've just written a quick enhancement to our CMS to automatically generate Selenium Selenese tests. This works great, but now I'm banging my head against the wall as Selenium IDE requires the test suites and files to be on the local filesystem.

Is there a way to get Selenium IDE to load test suites (and cases) from a URL instead of a filesystem path? That way I could just point Selenium IDE to the automatically generated test cases.

(I find this kind of ironic. It's a web test tool running in a web browser but can't access anything on the web... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE won't do that, but lots of command-line tools will.  Consider wrapping your IDE-startup in a script file (BAT on Windows, shell on Linux, *etc.*) that uses [wget](http://www.gnu.org/s/wget/) to download the files from the URLs, runs Firefox and IDE, and then deletes the files.